# How Do I Move My Tumblr Index Page To A Different Page?

Tags: blogs, tumblr, portfolio

I have my tumblr all set up and it works perfectly. However, I'm strapped for cash and can't afford to purchase a domain name at this time, so I thought I would use my index page on tumblr to act as the landing page for my portfolio. So when I visit name.tumblr.com, instead of seeing a list of blog entries, it looks just like a normal website. I've done, and that works perfectly as well. (It's not too professional, but I figure having something like name.tumblr.com looks a little better than name.freehosting.com.)

The problem arises when I take what used to be my tumblr index page and do a straight up copy and paste of the code into a new tumbr page (ie, name.tumblr.com/blog-page). Now when I visit name.tumblr.com/blog-page, my posts don't load. My stylesheet and all my graphics load, but the posts don't.

I was wondering if there was a way to make this work, to use a sub-page in tumblr as my blog rather than having it display on the index page.

Comment: Why not just use the archive page instead of `/blog-page` ?

Comment: That's a good idea, and I hadn't thought of it. However- at least as far as I know- I can't stylize the archive page. So it wouldn't work well with my layout for my portfolio that I just spent the last 70+ hours designing and coding, lol.

Comment: Hmmm, true, tumblr doesn't load your stylesheet for the archive page, but an `archive.css` page.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to do what you want.

There are other ways to fix your situation:

- make all your posts private until you buy domain;
- make your blog non-indexed with special metatag until you buy doamin;
- use subdomain.